# How to grant access to a specific table across all databases in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-5.7

I want to Grant access like so:

```
> GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON `%`.my_table TO 'user'@'%';
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table '%.my_table' doesn't exist
```

This is not possible per Mysql documentation on [grant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-quoting):

> The _ and % wildcards are permitted when specifying database names in
> GRANT statements that grant privileges at the database level

And nothing is mentioned for table level access.

I found similar questions on stackexchange, but they have different use cases. There is [Mysql Bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88694) from 2017 that seems to suggest a fix for this specific use case:

> Accept statements which have a wildcard in the database name and a
> fixed table name.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: *Is there a workaround?* No. Grant each table separately (use stored procedure, iterate over metadata).

Comment: *And nothing is mentioned for table level access.* Documentation claims: "Table privileges apply to all columns in a given table." ONE given table, not given table**S**.

Comment: @Akina that's one solution, however, I would need this to apply to future databases as well.

Comment: *I would need this to apply to future databases as well.* You must add according GRANT to future databases/tables creation code simply. Or to the code which performs this creation dynamically.

Comment: In general, having lots of "identical" tables is a no-no.  Is this Wordpress?  Or some other 3rd party software that you are trying to fix?

Comment: @RickJames Its custom-built, that's mapping every customer to a DB - not ideal, but that's how it's built.

Comment: My condolences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to script it in a stored procedure.

here is such a script

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS grantor;
USE grantor
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS grant_table $$
CREATE PROCEDURE grant_table
(
    tb VARCHAR(64)
   ,userhost VARCHAR(128)
   ,grantlist VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DBLIST;
    CREATE TABLE DBLIST
    (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        db VARCHAR(64),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) ENGINE=MEMORY;
    INSERT INTO DBLIST (db)
    SELECT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables WHERE
    table_schema NOT IN
    ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql','sys')
    AND table_name = tb;
    SELECT MAX(id) INTO @rcount FROM DBLIST;
    SELECT @rcount;
    SET @x = 0;
    WHILE @x < @rcount DO
        SET @x = @x + 1;
        SELECT CONCAT('GRANT ',grantlist,' ON `',db,'`.',tb,' TO ',userhost)
        INTO @sql
        FROM DBLIST WHERE id = @x;
        SELECT @sql;
        PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
    END WHILE;    

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a sample call

```
CREATE TABLE tryout.thistable (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE DMP492.thistable LIKE tryout.thistable;
CREATE TABLE DMP551.thistable LIKE tryout.thistable;
CREATE TABLE DMP579.thistable LIKE tryout.thistable;
CREATE TABLE DMP756.thistable LIKE tryout.thistable;
CALL grantor.grant_table('thistable','ptqd@''%''','INSERT,SELECT');
```

Here was a sample test I did

```
MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/grantor> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS grantor;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/grantor> USE grantor
Database changed
MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/grantor> DELIMITER $$
MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/grantor> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS grant_table $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/grantor> CREATE PROCEDURE grant_table
    -> (
    ->     tb VARCHAR(64)
    ->    ,userhost VARCHAR(128)
    ->    ,grantlist VARCHAR(255)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DBLIST;
    ->     CREATE TABLE DBLIST
    ->     (
    ->         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->         db VARCHAR(64),
    ->         PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ->     ) ENGINE=MEMORY;
    ->     INSERT INTO DBLIST (db)
    ->     SELECT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables WHERE
    ->     table_schema NOT IN
    ->     ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql','sys')
    ->     AND table_name = tb;
    ->     SELECT MAX(id) INTO @rcount FROM DBLIST;
    ->     SELECT @rcount;
    ->     SET @x = 0;
    ->     WHILE @x < @rcount DO
    ->         SET @x = @x + 1;
    ->         SELECT CONCAT('GRANT ',grantlist,' ON `',db,'`.',tb,' TO ',userhost)
    ->         INTO @sql
    ->         FROM DBLIST WHERE id = @x;
    ->         SELECT @sql;
    ->         PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
    ->     END WHILE;
    ->
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/grantor> DELIMITER ;
MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/grantor> CALL grantor.grant_table('thistable','ptqd@''%''','INSERT,SELECT');
+---------+
| @rcount |
+---------+
|       5 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+-------------------------------------------------------+
| @sql                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT INSERT,SELECT ON `DMP492`.thistable TO ptqd@'%' |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

+-------------------------------------------------------+
| @sql                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT INSERT,SELECT ON `DMP551`.thistable TO ptqd@'%' |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

+-------------------------------------------------------+
| @sql                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT INSERT,SELECT ON `DMP579`.thistable TO ptqd@'%' |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

+-------------------------------------------------------+
| @sql                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT INSERT,SELECT ON `DMP756`.thistable TO ptqd@'%' |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

+-------------------------------------------------------+
| @sql                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT INSERT,SELECT ON `tryout`.thistable TO ptqd@'%' |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/grantor> show grants for ptqd@'%';
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for ptqd@%                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'ptqd'@'%'                           |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `DMP492`.`thistable` TO 'ptqd'@'%' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `tryout`.`thistable` TO 'ptqd'@'%' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `DMP756`.`thistable` TO 'ptqd'@'%' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `DMP551`.`thistable` TO 'ptqd'@'%' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `DMP579`.`thistable` TO 'ptqd'@'%' |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL://localhost/root/mysqld.sock/grantor>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted, although did not use this procedure, as I had my own migration script to do the same.